# What is the difference between #/bin/sh and # ! /bin/sh?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

What is the difference between `#/bin/sh` and `# ! /bin/sh ?` and `#/bin/bash` in shell script file?
I am new to the shell script, I want to create a shell script file which will run the code.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux (and several other [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) systems) the `#!` (called [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and without spaces) is understood by [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) when it is the *first* line of some executable script and immediately followed by some executable file (called interpreter).

If you use Linux, read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) then [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)

#### Spaces (actually lack of most of them) are important.

You might write an executable [Python](https://python.org/) script starting with `#!/usr/bin/python`. Use [chmod(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chmod.1.html) to make it executable and see [inode(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html). You could also have some executable [GNU guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) script.

On some Linux distributions, `/bin/sh` is a [symlink(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/symlink.7.html) to `/bin/bash` (that is [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)). But on others, to `/bin/dash` (see [DASH](http://gondor.apana.org.au/%7Eherbert/dash/) website). [This](https://www.difference.wiki/bash-vs-dash/) explains some differences between them.

And GNU bash has a documented behavior. So read [its documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html).

#### And GNU bash is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html).

**So you are allowed to study its source code and improve it**.

Also, `dash` is (like [sash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell)) open source. You can study its source code and improve it.

Read also [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) then [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and [bash(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html).

Notice that `/bin/sh` is documented in POSIX standards.

My favorite Linux shell is [zsh](https://zsh.org/). You could try [fish](https://fishshell.org/) (coded in C++, open source) or [es](http://wryun.github.io/es-shell/), and set your login shell with [chsh(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chsh.1.html) (see [passwd(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/passwd.5.html) and [shells(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/shells.5.html)...)

As an exercise, **you could even *write* your own [Unix shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell)**. You could want to use [GNU readline](https://www.gnu.org/software/readline/) inside it. See also [path_resolution(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html) and [glob(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html).

#### You certainly would learn a lot by reading the source code of your favorite shell.

Some shells accept [plugins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)) (see [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and [dlsym(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html)...). You could write one for them.

> I want to create a shell script file which will run the code.

I recommend to use both [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) and [git](https://git-scm.com/) for that purpose. But keep your shell script small. For large scripts (more than a few hundred lines), use something better than GNU bash.

In some cases, a shell script is generated. An example of such generator is [GNU autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/).

Answer (score 1):

The first two bytes in a file make up an 16-bit-integer known as [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29), from which the operating system can derive how to handle this file. For certain magic numbers, the subsequent bytes are used to further differentiate into more detail. The magic number (written in hex) 2321 defines that this is a textfile which can be executed by some language processor (bash, perl, m4,....), and the subsequent bytes denote the language processor to be actually used. If you look up 2321 in the ASCII table, it is `#!`.

Your other two examples don't denote a valid magic number.

You don't need to provide the #! line if you don't want to (though it is often a good idea to do so), since you can always, when executing a script, write explicitly how it is to be processed.

For instance, if you have a file `foo` which is supposed to be run by bash, you can either start it with i.e. (depending on where bash is located on your system)

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
```

or, if you want *bash* to be located via your PATH, by

```
#!/usr/local/bin/env bash
```

and set the executable bit on your script,

```
chmod u+x foo
```

and then invoke the script by simply typing

```
./foo
```

or don't do any of this preparation work and invoke your script by

```
bash ./foo
```

**UPDATE** : As triplee pointed out, the solution involving `env` should be better written as

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

even if /usr/local/bin happens to exist on your platform, because it makes porting the scripts to different hosts easier (`/usr/bin/env` is supposed to exist in hopefully any Linux- or BSD-setting, including MacOS).

Comment: Maybe emphasize that `#` when not immediately followed by `!` is just a comment.

Comment: `#!/usr/local/bin/env` will most probably not exist; most places these days the correct shebang would be `#!/usr/bin/env`

Comment: @tripleee : That's why I mentioned that the OP has to adopt the pathes to his environment. I just copied the setup from my own environment for laziness, where the `env` is in `/usr/local/bin` and in `/usr/bin`.  I agree that in particular with `env`, for compatibility with other platforms `/usr/bin` would be the preferred choice, and I will update my answer correspondingly.